# Sending via specific SMTP credentials in Rails, whitelisted IP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, smtp, ip, whitelist

I want to send mails using specific smtp credentials (those of a Gmail account) from my rails app.
The problem I encounter is that the IP specified in the resulting email is likely to be blacklisted (actually, as I'm using Heroku, it is blacklisted).

Does anybody know a way to send from a whitelisted IP / rewrite this IP, while still using those SMTP credentials?

I tried to use things like Proximo but it doesn't seem to support SMTP...

Thanks,